# missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg' materialization_incremental_clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse, dbt

I am trying to set up an incremental model in dbt with clickhouse. The following configuration works "fine". Dbt is able to build my table.

```
{{
    config(
        materialized = 'incremental',
        unique_key = 'transaction_id',
        indexes=[
          {'columns': ['transaction_id'], 'type': 'btree', 'unique': True },
          {'columns': ['last_mod'], 'type': 'btree'}
        ]
    )
}}

SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
FROM postgresql('host:port', 'db_name', 'table_name', 'db_user', 'db_password', 'schema')
```

in my profiles.yml:

```
local_clickhouse:
      type: clickhouse
      schema: warehouse_dev
      user: "{{ env_var('CLICKHOUSE_USER') }}"
      password: "{{ env_var('CLICKHOUSE_PASS') }}"
      port: 9000
      host: localhost
      cluster: default
      retries: 1
      connect_timeout: 10
      send_receive_timeout: 3600 # 1hr
      use_lw_deletes: true
```

But when updating the macro in my model I get an error. I would like to use the `ReplicatedMergeTree` engine because I am querying my data from some BI tools and when doing the requests from those tools it seems like 2/3 of the time I'm hitting to a server with no data. Updated macro:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized = 'incremental',
        engine = 'ReplicatedMergeTree',
        unique_key = 'transaction_id',
        indexes=[
          {'columns': ['transaction_id'], 'type': 'btree', 'unique': True },
          {'columns': ['last_mod'], 'type': 'btree'}
        ]
    )
}}
```

Error shown:

```
Compilation Error in model stg_transaction_event_card (models/prd/staging/stg_transaction_event_card.sql)
18:44:20    DbtRuntimeError.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
18:44:20    
18:44:20    > in macro materialization_incremental_clickhouse (macros/materializations/incremental.sql)
18:44:20    > called by model stg_transaction_event_card (models/prd/staging/stg_transaction_event_card.sql)
```

Comment: i think better ask questions here https://github.com/ClickHouse/dbt-clickhouse/issues